# Can you stack AC bonuses with an Artificer's Infusions?

Tags: dnd-5e, stacking, artificer, armor-class, artificer-infusions

Can you stack AC bonuses with an Artificer's Infusions?

I get that you can't use the same Infusion on multiple items. However... does the Enhance Defense Infusion and Repulsion Shield Infusion stack in AC bonuses.

- Enhance Defense Infusion +1 AC (+2 at Lv10)
- Repulsion Shield Infusion +1 AC (Knock back ability)

So an Artificer at Lv 10 with Full Plate (AC 18), with a shield (AC +2) total AC 20 can tech have a total AC of 23 right?

Comment: Is there a reason you think they might *not* work together?

Comment: Please review the [help article on how to ask a good question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, that article states: “Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!” It is time to start showing that you can put some effort into researching before asking questions.

Comment: What about this question is unclear?

Comment: @Akixkisu I believe the point of confusion is unclear, as Thomas Markov points out. Without further details, it's entirely possible that an answer would be unintentionally misleading, due to some other misunderstanding. The question appears so straightforward that it's reasonable to assume that we're missing a key point of confusion.

Comment: @RedOrca "You can't stack same infusions, but can you stack same/similar boni from different infusions?" is a simple and stackable question about stacking, one among hundreds of questions that we have answered about the topic of stacking. It points out the source of confusion without ambiguity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes

Enhanced defense requires: A suit of armor or a shield, and says

> A creature gains a +1 bonus to Armor Class while wearing (armor) or wielding (shield) the infused item.  The bonus increases to +2 when you reach 10th level in this class.

Repulsion Shield requires: A shield and an attunement slot, and says:

> A creature gains a +1 bonus to Armor Class while wielding this shield.

As you say, only one infusion may be cast on an item at a time, but if the Artificer has infused their armor with *enhanced defense* and their shield with *repulsion shield*, there is nothing to prevent both of these bonuses being applied to the Artificer's AC.  These 'stack' in the same way a PC might have *Plate Mail +2* and a *Shield +1* and receive the magic bonuses for both.  Your calculation of AC23 at 10th level is correct.

In the party I run, the Artificer is the tank, uses specifically this combination to achieve an AC23, and then further casts *Blur* to have attacks on him made at disadvantage and uses *Thunder Gauntlets* to have attacks on others made at disadvantage.  It is a powerful combination but legal.  Fortunately they are currently in *Rise of Tiamat* so I have lots of Saving Throw based attacks (rather than attack roll based attacks) to target him with.